# WiFi garage door controller installation

Tags: wiring, garage, garage-door-opener

Currently I have the normal garage door remote but in addition to it I would like to add a WiFi controlled system.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/du79B.jpg Those pictures show the current control box and the new one. But I can't figure out how to connect the cables for both to work at the same time.

Also in the picture I circled in purple the cables that connect to a laser sensor (that it's supposed to stop if something crosses it, but it doesn't, even though I could see the lights changing in it when I break the beam). How could I test what's wrong with it?

Thank you!

Comment: Has the laser sensor ever worked?  Have you looked at the manual and compared your wiring?

Comment: Hi, I bought this house last year and I don't know how long it's been like that., I don't think the laser sensor is broken since it's detecting when I cross it.. but never stopped the door from opening or closing.. I don't know what brand it is

Comment: I googled the terminology from the PCB:  V5 Rollertec http://abigaragedoors.co.uk/pdf/somfy/rollertech_install_guide.pdf

Comment: @mike65535 That's very informative I think that might have the information I need to attach the new controller. and the laser detector. Do  you think I need to remove the link between T17 and T18 for that? also if I connect the new device switches to T13 and T15, and Comm to T14.. that should work, right?

Comment: It's hard to tell what the correct wiring is;  I found it difficult to interpret.  I would definitely try to get the sensor working first.

Comment: Thanks @mike65535 I'll try that today.. another question I have is to power the new device (it needs from 90-240V) can I just add a cable from the current system to the new one or have it's own socket?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "its own socket".  Does the new device have a regular AC plug? If so then it must be plugged into a wall outlet (or extension cord etc).  If you mean something else please clarify.  Could you provide make/model etc ?

Comment: BTW, best I can tell from the docs, the jumper (link) you have between T17 and T18 is to be REMOVED if there is a sensor.

Comment: @mike65535 regarding the power.. the new device as you can see in this picture: https://i.imgur.com/lQECQ4G.jpg accepts from 90V to 240V AC so I was wondering if you could wire it to the current controller (https://i.imgur.com/zGFXxsH.jpg) in T1 & T2 so both controllers get the power from the same socket. As for the T17/T18 I'll try that today.. Thanks